# h2 database unit test across multiple schema

Tags: database, unit-testing, h2

I am trying to use unit test along with h2 database. My application uses MSSQL database. And below are the 2 table that am using in my application:

```
SchemaA.dbo.Table1<br>
SchemaB.dbo.table2<br>

@Entity<br>
@Table(name="SchemaB..table")<br>
Class A <br>
{

  private Long id;

  ............

}
```

I am trying to write unit test to test  the persistance of the above class. But h2 database does not recognise this tablename syntax:

SchemaB..table

Note : the 2 dots between schema name and table name.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to use the schema attribute of the Table JPA annotation.
For example:

```
@Entity(name = "Foo")
@Table(name = "TABLE_FOO", schema = "bar")
```

If you have a single data source, which connects to your h2 with user A. In order to access schema 'bar', you may want to tell h2 to automatically create schema 'bar' on connect.

```
jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MySQL;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'test/init.sql'
```

The final part of the JDBC URL test/init.sql points to a sql file with the following content.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS bar
```

H2 will execute the sql and create the schema on connect.

---

I've created a demo project at [github](https://github.com/sohoffice/demo_h2_multi_schemas).

The project has an init.sql file that creates 2 schema, foo and bar.

2 model classes foo.A and bar.B that use @Entity(schema="foo", name="A") to specify schema accordingly. see app/models.

The test case uses play framework therefore the built-in evolution tool can be applied every time test cases are executed. But it should be fine to use setUp method to apply your own sql script before executing test cases. Please see test folder for the sample test case. (it's actually scalaTest but it basically has the same idea as junit)

Comment: can we have multiple schema (more than one) in the same h2 database?

Comment: Hi @TinyOS, I don't see why not. I just started h2 console (by running java -jar h2-1.4.185.jar), and created 2 schema foo and bar. Looks good to me.

Comment: Hi @Douglas Liu , i used a sql file where i made all schemas whitch i need and in the persistance.xml i made reload that file :

`jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MySQL;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'test/schema.sql'`

Comment: Hi @TinyOS, I've created an demo project that uses 2 schemas with JPA+H2. Please see the edited answer.