# Hibernate: Create psql schema before the tables

Tags: java, hibernate

I am currently developing various junit tests for hibernate. Some Hibernate model classes refer to a different schema as "public". For example, the schema "internal". Now I have to create this schema "internally" before the tables are created. How do I get this implemented with Hibernate?

Test.java

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Table.class);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.h2.Driver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:mem:test");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    this.sf = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    this.injector = Guice.createInjector(new CoreModule());
    this.injector.injectMembers(this);
    Key<SimpleScope> simpleScopeKey = Key.get(SimpleScope.class, Names.named("scriptingScope"));
    this.scope = this.injector.getInstance(simpleScopeKey);
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    this.sf.close();
}
```

Table.java

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "internal", name = "table")
public class Table {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Error

```
Schema "RIS" not found; SQL statement:    
create table internal.table (id bigint not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) [90079-193]
Feb 13, 2017 10:52:20 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305778/h2-database-unit-test-across-multiple-schema**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this problem can be found here: https://touk.pl/blog/2011/01/18/hibernate-hbm2ddl-wont-create-schema-before-creating-tables/